# jquery focus selector is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tryed to do `alert( $(":focus").attr("id") );` 
along with I tryed

```
$("input").each(function(){ 
    $('#debug').val( $(this).is(":focus") + $('#debug').val());
});
```

The first one alerts ( Undefined ) and the second one fills the debug selector with false

any idea's? It is apearing that the :focus

I am running jquery version 1.7.1
And testing in chrome

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If you are executing this on a button click, your input elements will never have focus, the button will. Some context might be helpful.

Comment: I figured it out, I was running the $(":focus") onblur

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way, this is the approach I've typically taken on the selector level to determine if an element is of a certain selector.

```
$(this).filter(":focus").size()
```